# How to install Java 9 and Gradle in a Docker image

Tags: java, gradle, dockerfile

I try to install OpenJDK9 and Gradle 4.5.1 in a Docker image.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER Hari Sekhon (https://www.linkedin.com/in/harisekhon)

LABEL Description="Java + Ubuntu (OpenJDK)"

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

ARG JAVA_VERSION=9
ARG JAVA_RELEASE=JDK

ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr

RUN bash -c ' \
    set -euxo pipefail && \
    apt-get update && \
    pkg="openjdk-$JAVA_VERSION"; \
    if [ "$JAVA_RELEASE" = "JDK" ]; then \
        pkg="$pkg-jdk-headless"; \
    else \
        pkg="$pkg-jre-headless"; \
    fi; \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends "$pkg" && \
    apt-get clean'


CMD /bin/bash

#install Gradle
RUN wget -q https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.5.1-bin.zip \
    && unzip gradle-4.5.1-bin.zip -d /opt \
    && rm gradle-4.5.1-bin.zip

# Set Gradle in the environment variables
ENV GRADLE_HOME /opt/gradle-4.5.1
ENV PATH $PATH:/opt/gradle-4.5.1/bin
```

And I am getting an error:

> `ubuntu@automation-ubuntu-17:~/dockerFiles$ The command '/bin/sh -c
>   bash -c '     set -euxo pipefail &&     apt-get update &&
>
>   pkg="openjdk-$JAVA_VERSION";     if [ "$JAVA_RELEASE" = "JDK" ]; then 
>   pkg="$pkg-jdk-headless";     else         pkg="$pkg-jre-headless";
>
>   fi;     apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends "$pkg" &&
>
>   apt-get clean'' returned a non-zero code: 100`

Comment: Why don't you just use a provided jdk9 image provided on [dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk/)?

Comment: I think that there is a problem to install on ubuntu openJDK 9 and gradle

Comment: Does using ubuntu:16.04, as per my answer, fix your problem? Or do you need to use 18.04 for some reason?

Answer (score 1):

The `ubuntu:latest` tag is currently `ubuntu:18.04` (bionic), which only contains the [java packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/java/) for [openjdk-8-jdk-headless](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/java/openjdk-8-jdk-headless) and [openjdk-11-jdk-headless](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/java/openjdk-11-jdk-headless) but not openjdk-9-jdk-headless (which has already reached [end-of-life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history), at least for public updates).

[openjdk-9-jdk-headless](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/openjdk-9-jdk-headless) is available in `ubuntu:16.04` (xenial), though.

I got the build working by switching to `ubuntu:16.04`, and also adding `wget` and `unzip` to the list of packages to install as they are subsequently used to download and unpack gradle but are not installed by default.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
MAINTAINER Hari Sekhon (https://www.linkedin.com/in/harisekhon)

LABEL Description="Java + Ubuntu (OpenJDK)"

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

ARG JAVA_VERSION=9
ARG JAVA_RELEASE=JDK

ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr

RUN bash -c ' \
    set -euxo pipefail && \
    apt-get update && \
    pkg="openjdk-$JAVA_VERSION"; \
    if [ "$JAVA_RELEASE" = "JDK" ]; then \
        pkg="$pkg-jdk-headless"; \
    else \
        pkg="$pkg-jre-headless"; \
    fi; \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends wget unzip "$pkg" && \
    apt-get clean'


CMD /bin/bash

#install Gradle
RUN wget -q https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.5.1-bin.zip \
    && unzip gradle-4.5.1-bin.zip -d /opt \
    && rm gradle-4.5.1-bin.zip

# Set Gradle in the environment variables
ENV GRADLE_HOME /opt/gradle-4.5.1
ENV PATH $PATH:/opt/gradle-4.5.1/bin
```